# How to create a loop to read several images in a python script?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I use python to work with image processing. I'm used to cut, draw and other things, but for one image. Like in the script below, how can i aply a loop in the script to do for several images?

```
import PIL

import Image

im=Image.open('test.tif')

box=(50, 50, 200, 200)

im_crop=im.crop(box)

im_crop.show()
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to wrap it in a `for` loop, and give that loop a list of files.

One very easy way to get a list of all the TIF files in the current directory is with `glob`, like this:

```
import PIL
import Image
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    box=(50, 50, 200, 200)
    im_crop=im.crop(box)
    im_crop.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import PIL
import Image

filelist = ['test.tif','test2.tif']
for imagefile in filelist:
    im=Image.open(imagefile)
    box=(50, 50, 200, 200)
    im_crop=im.crop(box)
    im_crop.show()
```

Just add the filenames to the list `filelist`. The `for` loop iterates over each element of the list and assigns the current value to `imagefile`. You can use `imagefile` in the body of your loop to process the image.

Comment: Can we use glob with `os.walk`, recursive searches? or do we have to `os.walk` and `filter(regex_search, list)`. update: i can use fnmatch instead, which is almost the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
import PIL

import Image

images = ["test.tif", "test2.tif", "test3.tif"]

for imgName in images:
    im=Image.open(imgName)

    box=(50, 50, 200, 200)

    im_crop=im.crop(box)

    im_crop.show()
```